# Overwriting max-width of child page

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, master-pages

In my master page I have this code:

```
<div id="body">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" />
        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="MainContent" />
        </section>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.content-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 960px;
}
```

For most child pages 960px width is fine but there are instances where I would like to change that to something like 1200px

What would I need to overwrite in order to change the 960 value to 1200 or even the full width of the current resolution?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
    .content-wrapper {
       margin: 0 auto;
       max-width: 960px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create 2 sub master pages of `master960` and `master1200` that inherit the main master and only have a section with the specific width.

```
<%@ Master Inherits="mymainmaster" %>
<section class="content-wrapper-1200">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="MainContent" />
</section>

<%@ Master Inherits="mymainmaster" %>
<section class="content-wrapper-960">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="MainContent" />
</section>
```

Comment: So create 2 separate master pages with different css classes set?